# How to add hard negative examples in Tensorflow object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am training pre-trained SSD on my custom dataset which is working fine with test images. But when a new image comes with no object(hard negative), it detects false positive. I was looking for a way for adding these hard negative examples in training but did not find an exact procedure. Could someone help me out here?

1. How do I add hard negative examples to training?
2. Do I have to create XML files/ bounding boxes for hard negative images?
3. How do I create tf records for these hard negative images?
4. Do I have to edit code files to generate tf records or config file?

Comment: This question is already answered, please refer to the answers in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351307/tensorflow-object-dectection-api-how-to-create-tfrecords-with-images-not-conta/61782625#61782625

Comment: @Malgo Thanks for adding answer. But I think I found I workaround which gets the job done. Its by adding a dummy class in all hard negative examples and training the model.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your answer here, it will be helpful

Comment: Answer: 1. Create a dummy class that will be added to the training. e.g. Suppose you are training a model to detect persons who are far away from the camera. You have some images where there is no person(hard negative), just add these images to the training set by annotating them with some dummy class by creating bounding boxes to any side of the image. 2. Train the model using both classes. (Person and dummy) By doing this the model will perform better on hard negative examples with fewer false positives. Hopes this answer is sufficient.